# Export list to excel using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, export, export-to-excel

I'm trying to export a dynamic list to excel/notepad/notepad++/word.
I saw ways to export table to excel but this doesn't solve my problem.
My unordered list contains several lists (changeable) and the value that I want to export is the value of the input from type text(value_to_export).
How can I export all these lists values?
Thanks?

```
<ul>
<li id="0" class="list">
<input type="checkbox" class="" id="" value="">
<input type="text" id="" title="" class="" value="value_to_export">
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of li you can use HTML table.

table2excel is a simple yet useful jQuery plugin which allows for exporting Html table data to an Excel file.

```js
< script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" > < /script>
<script src="src/jquery.table2excel.js "></script>
```

2. Create an 'Export' button to export table data to an Excel file manually. Optional.

```html
<button>Export</button>
```

3. Call the plugin on the table and done.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#table2excel").table2excel({
    // exclude CSS class
    exclude: ".noExl",
    name: "Excel Document Name"
  }); 
});
```

4. You can add the CSS class 'noExl' to any tr tags to ignore the specified table data while exporting.

```html
<tr class="noExl">
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Column heading</th>
  <th>Column heading</th>
  <th>Column heading</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: I can't change the list to a table, it must be in a list formation. I only want to add the feature that will copy the values to clipboard. Does it possible? Thanks a lot! @Adi Ruban

Comment: you can try "list" also just modify the code table  to list and try that sample

Comment: There is a way to export text from a single variable to excel? I think it should be easier to implement this in my code... I don't succeed to implement this plugin with list. @Adi Ruban